# Why is Grub installed multiple times on my system?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

### Background

I have Win10, Manjaro, and Artix installed on my system. However, both Manjaro and Artix have their own grub installation. Currently, there exist no issues but, I would prefer to install more distros for testing without additional installations of grub. No graphical installation tool ever asked me if I have grub already installed or if I don't want to install grub.

### Issue

Why does each distro have its own installation of grub? and how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Why `wouldn't` you have one for each distro?

Comment: I don't see the point of multiple instances of grub on my system. With one instance of grub, I can do everything what I need to do. I can customize it. My grub config is only applied in this one grub instance.

Comment: If you just want to test other distros you could use something like virtualbox.

Comment: @mnille I know, but it is not the same as bare metal. I don't have many resources to work with(4GB RAM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB can be installed in several different ways, and there has been no standardization between different distributions.

Because of the various complications of the PC system architecture, setting up a bootloader whose capabilities are known is difficult enough on its own. Trying to work with an unknown version of GRUB with unknown capabilities (will it support software RAID? LVM? Which LUKS encryption methods?) has been something distribution maintainers have been unwilling to tackle. And when an OS that is not the "owner" of a particular GRUB installation has a kernel update installed, it would need to know the correct procedure to update the GRUB configuration to adjust its own boot entries to match the actual kernel versions available, which is not trivial when there are multiple distributions using the same GRUB.

Along with `systemd` was introduced `systemd-boot`, and it includes a scheme that allows each distribution to specify its desired kernel and initramfs files and boot options in a program-readable way. This is known as the [Boot Loader Specification](https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_SPECIFICATION/), and e.g. RHEL 8's GRUB now uses the relatively new `blscfg` GRUB module to read those specifications and construct a boot menu dynamically at boot time, instead of relying on a pre-configured menu.

If this specification becomes supported by most major distributions, it would open the way to solving this "one GRUB with multiple OSs" problem. Time will tell if it'll be successful or not.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It barrels me, even tho many people in the Linux community have the x-program is bloated minimalist mindset, this is still a problem. Hopefully some day it won't be an issue anymore.